# Matplotlib quiver error

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I've spent several days trying to understand how to plot wind vectors over contours using quiver and I remain befuddled. I get the following error when trying to run my code:

[Quiver error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1nMj.png)

File links:

[myfile1.nc](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=31661851372746593819)

[myfile2.nc](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=79985975865233723998)

What am I doing wrong here? From the quiver documentation, it looks like it expects quiver(X,Y,U,V) where X and Y are the coordinates and U and V represent the data for the arrows. I thought that's what I had setup here?

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset as NetCDFFile
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

nc = NetCDFFile('myfile1.nc')
nc1 = NetCDFFile('myfile2.nc')
lat = nc.variables['lat'][:]
lon = nc.variables['lon'][:]
time = nc.variables['time'][:]
uwnd = nc.variables['uwnd'][:]
vwnd = nc1.variables['vwnd'][:]
map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=180.,llcrnrlat=0.,urcrnrlon=340.,urcrnrlat=80.)
lons,lats = np.meshgrid(lon,lat)
x,y = map(lons,lats)
speed = np.sqrt(uwnd*uwnd+vwnd*vwnd)
levels = np.arange(0.4,3.0,0.1)
ticks = np.arange(0.0,3.0,0.2)
cs = map.contourf(x,y,speed[0],levels, cmap=cmap)
plt.quiver(x,y,uwnd,vwnd)
cbar = plt.colorbar(cs, orientation='horizontal', cmap=cmap, 
spacing='proportional',ticks=ticks)
cbar.set_label('850 mb Vector Wind Anomalies (m/s)')
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawparallels(np.arange(20,80,20),labels=[1,1,0,0], linewidth=0.5)
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(200,340,20),labels=[0,0,0,1], linewidth=0.5)
plt.savefig('phase8_850wind_anom_test.png',dpi=600)
```

Comment: I guess because noone except you knows what `nc.variables['uwnd'][:]` is, one cannot help here. Note however that you are using two different data `nc`, `nc1` so maybe they are different? Please read and understand [mcve].

Comment: The wind data I'm trying to plot is comprised of a west-east component 'uwnd' and a north-south component 'vwnd'. I've successfully contoured the wind speeds from that data but am attempting to overlay the wind vectors on top. I edited my original post to add more of the code and added download links to my input files.